# Xslt template. xsl if not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to create 2 tables one that display when is greater and one for when is less. The first table is working fine but creating a second table is not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <!-- template that is use for root-->
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <html>
      <!--Displays a heading above the list of movie title-->
      <head>
        <title> Movies</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <!--Displays a heading above the list of movie title-->
        <h1 align="center">
          <font color="red" size="10">Movies  Listing</font>
        </h1>
        <!-- Creates the table-->
        <table style="color:blue;" bgcolor="gray" cellpadding="5" border="1" align="center">
          <tr style="font-family:arial; color:blue;">
            <td>Movie ID</td>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td> Movie Year</td>
          </tr>
          <!-- apply template stament to use the template for movie-->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="movies/movie">
            <xsl:sort select="title" order="ascending"></xsl:sort>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>

      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- template for each movie element-->

  <xsl:template match="movie">
    <xsl:if test="year&lt;2005">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@id"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Director"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="year"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="year">
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="year">
    <table>
      <tr style="font-family:arial; color:blue;">
        <td>Movie ID</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td> Movie Year</td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:if test="year&gt;=2005">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@id"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Director"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="year"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:if>  
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- template for color and font use for text in each element-->
  <xsl:template match="@id">
    <span style="font-family:arial; color:blue;">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </span>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <span style="font-family:arial; color:blue;">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </span>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Director">
    <span style="font-family:arial; color:blue;">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </span>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="year">
    <span style="font-family:arial; color:blue;">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </span>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I created an if statement but is only working for the first table. Can I do a choose statement to create both table and test the element?

Comment: Can you share the input XML? Also you have tagged the question to `XSLT 2.0` whereas you are using `XSLT 1.0` version in your shared XSLT. Please confirm on the version you are using.

Answer (score 2):

In the `match="year"` template, you use the condition `test="year>=2005"`. A bare name `year` in an XPath expression means `./child::year`, that is, select the `year` children of the context node. But the context node is a `year` element, and I doubt it has a child called `year`. Use `test=".>=2005"`.

I suspect that the `year` element doesn't have children called `title` or `Director` either. I suspect what you really want is to have one template rule with `match="movie[year>=2005]"` and one with `match="movie[year<2005]"`.

But since you haven't shown your input or expected output, it's hard to know exactly what you are trying to achieve.